# How to update each column based on previous column using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have data that consists of an id variable and then multiple visit variables that track a persons score over time. I am trying to carry the score forward, updating any subsequent zeros to that score. If there is an NA I would like to leave it (representing no visit) and if a person gets a new score later, I would like the new score to carry forward.

I have included a tiny reproducible example, but my actual data is quite large, so manually updating is not an option. My current attempts are to use a for loop to loop through the visit columns for each person (row). However I am getting this warning:

Error in if ((!is.na(first) & first != 0) & (!is.na(second) & second ==  : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(second) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

It looks to be because in the environment (Rstuio) first has a value of NA_real_ and second has a value of NULL (empty).

How do I properly define these?
I don't have much experience in for loops, so all advice is welcome!

```
id <- c(101, 102, 103, 104)
visit.1 <- c(0, 21, 0, 21)
visit.2 <- c(0, 0, 50, 0)
visit.3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 44)
visit.4 <- c(NA, NA, 0, 0)
dat <- data.frame(id, visit.1, visit.2, visit.3, visit.4)


for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  for(j in 2:ncol(dat)){

    first <- dat[i, j]
    second <- dat[i,(j+1)]

    if((!is.na(first) & first != 0) & (!is.na(second) & second == 0)){
      second <- first
      } else {
        second <- second
      }
   }
  }
```

The original dataset:

```
id visit.1 visit.2 visit.3 visit.4
1 101       0       0       0      NA
2 102      21       0       0      NA
3 103       0      50       0       0
4 104      21       0      44       0
```

The desired end result:

```
id visit.1 visit.2 visit.3 visit.4
1 101       0       0       0      NA
2 102      21      21      21      NA
3 103       0      50      50      50
4 104      21      21      44      44
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple approach is to eliminate the inner loop and vectorize the inner replacement loop.  This is not the best solution but closer to what you are more familiar with:

```
id <- c(101, 102, 103, 104)
visit.1 <- c(0, 21, 0, 21)
visit.2 <- c(0, 0, 50, 0)
visit.3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 44)
visit.4 <- c(NA, NA, 0, 0)
dat <- data.frame(id, visit.1, visit.2, visit.3, visit.4)

for (index in 3:5){
  dat[[index]]<-ifelse(dat[[index]]==0, dat[[index-1]], dat[[index]])
}
```

I am using the for loop to move from column to column.  Then the ifelse is looking at the entire column.  For the rows that ==0 use the value to the left, if not use the current value.

Answer (score 2):

Dave2e answered your question with much less lines of code but I modified your attempt just slightly so that you can see what exactly you did wrong:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(newdat)){
  for(j in 3:ncol(newdat)) {

    first <- newdat[i, j-1]
    second <- newdat[i, j]

    if(!is.na(first) & !is.na(second) & second == 0){
      newdat[i,j] <- first
    }
  }
}
```

First of all with `dat[i,(j+1)]` you count one too much in `for(j in 2:ncol(dat)){ ... }`, so i used `3:ncol(dat)` and set the `first <- newdat[i, j-1]`.
Secondly `second <- first` wont work you need to address the dataframe directly.

Answer (score 2):

Another base R method will be to us `ave`

```
cbind(dat[1],t(apply(dat[-1],1,function(x)ave(x,cumsum(x),FUN=sum))))
   id visit.1 visit.2 visit.3 visit.4
1 101       0       0       0      NA
2 102      21      21      21      NA
3 103       0      50      50      50
4 104      21      21      44      44
```

A `data.table` format. No loops involved:

```
library(data.table)
A=setDT(melt(dat,1))[,.(variable,ave(value,cumsum(value),FUN=sum)),by=id]
dcast(A,id~variable,value.var = "V2")
   id visit.1 visit.2 visit.3 visit.4
1 101       0       0       0      NA
2 102      21      21      21      NA
3 103       0      50      50      50
4 104      21      21      44      44
```

Answer (score 1):

`zoo::na.locf` could be used here

```
library(zoo)
data <- tail(t(dat), -1)

        # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# visit.1    0   21    0   21
# visit.2    0    0   50    0
# visit.3    0    0    0   44
# visit.4   NA   NA    0    0

placeholder_value <- function(mat) {
    head(setdiff(seq(0, max(c(mat), na.rm=TRUE), 1), unique(c(mat))), 1)
}
val <- placeholder_value(data)
```

Since `na.locf` searches for `NA` values to impute, `NA` values are changed to a placeholder value before running `na.locf` (and `0` is changed to `NA`), and then these values are converted back to original values.

```
impute_vals <- function(header, data, val) {
    data <- replace(data, is.na(data), val)      # replace NA with placeholder value
    data <- replace(data, data==0, NA)           # replace 0 with NA for na.locf
    data <- apply(data, 2, function(i) zoo::na.locf(i, na.rm=FALSE))
    data <- rbind(header, data)
    data <- t(data)
    data <- replace(data, is.na(data), 0)        # revert to original values
    data <- replace(data, data==val, NA)
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    data
}

impute_vals(head(t(dat), 1), data, val)

   # id visit.1 visit.2 visit.3 visit.4
# 1 101       0       0       0      NA
# 2 102      21      21      21      NA
# 3 103       0      50      50      50
# 4 104      21      21      44      44
```